# How to minimize a two nexted summations?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

my problem is: I want to multiply a bidimensional array of values A by a vector of weights W (A*transpose(W)) but I do not know W but I know the result of the multiplication R, so, I want to estimate the weights W which multiplying A give R as a result.

I suppose it is minimization function by using a langragarian approach 
The function is

$
\sum_{i=1}^{l}(\sum_{k=1}^{R}a_{ijk}*w_k -v_i)
$

with constraints

$\sum_{k=1}^{R}w_k = 1$

and

$w_k \geq 0$, k =0,1,2,.., R

but I do not know how to continue.

Thank you

Comment: Does $k$ start at 0 or 1?  Is $R$ a vector or an index?  What is $v_i$?  Do you maybe want to minimize the absolute differences or squared differences?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes.
k starts at 1.
$v_i$ are the values of R (the result). it is just a multiplication A*W = R  then  A*W-R = 0


I want to minize the square differences (I forgot the square)

$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{ijk}*w_k -v_i)^2$

Comment: I just want to calculate the weights for any multiplication as in this example (but in a generic way and assuming that the solution is not exact)

\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 4\\ 
 3& 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}
w1 \\ w2
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix}

Thank you

Comment: Please make the corrections by editing your question. You can use a quadratic programming solver to solve this problem.